# Смена JSON файла с помощью AJAX используя javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Перелопатил уже кучу статей, но ничего толком да и не нашёл. У меня есть JSON-файл, который лежит на сервере. Мне нужно, чтобы пользователь вводил определённые данные в форме, и в JSON-файле создавался новый объект, в котором было бы то, что он ввёл.
Как это сделать на чистом JavaScript, если у вас есть ответ, то можете присылать код даже без проверки на браузер и всё в этом духе.

Заранее вам спасибо.

Comment: Если вы имеете в виду javascript, который находится в браузере, то никак, а если вы имеет в виду javascript на сервере в составе nodeJS, то тогда копайте в том направлении.

Comment: пользователь вводит определённые данные в форме -> отправляется запрос с данными на сервер -> обработчик принимает данные и обновляет JSON файл. Непонятно в чем заключается проблема.